# Posting link at facebook fan page

Tags: php, facebook

This is the array i want to post:

```
Array
(
    [access_token] => my_token
    [message] => You intend to work in USA? Do not miss this opportunity and candidate you now! www.iprojobs.com/details/job-for-finance-manager/10317
    [name] => Finance Manager
    [caption] => USA > IL > Finance
    [link] => www.iprojobs.com/details/job-for-finance-manager/10317
    [description] => Apply to this job at ContextMedia
    [picture] => http://www.iprojobs.com/images/logotipo.png
)
```

The link is correct. If i remove the link, the array is posted at facebook. If i don't remove the link it gives me an error:

> (#1) An error occured while creating the share

Comment: thks. Same error! I've tried with http://, with www. and without www.

Comment: it may be occur because of post limitation based on page_id or user_id, try after some hours or day interval, you can check with other page will help

Comment: I've think that to, but my "export" of information to that page was 115 posts yesterday. i've tried with another page.

Comment: senthilbp: You may have some reason. I've tried with other page i've created to this effect and it works with link http://www.iprojobs.com/details/job-for-finance-manager/10318, but, in www.facebook.com/iprojobs, why it works if i remove the link from the array and don't work with link? it's strange!!

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding http:// in link parameter

```
Array
(
    [access_token] => my_token
    [message] => You intend to work in USA? Do not miss this opportunity and candidate you now! www.iprojobs.com/details/job-for-finance-manager/10317
    [name] => Finance Manager
    [caption] => USA > IL > Finance
    [link] => http://www.iprojobs.com/details/job-for-finance-manager/10317
    [description] => Apply to this job at ContextMedia
    [picture] => http://www.iprojobs.com/images/logotipo.png
)
```